# Several keys of the keyboard stopped working on my laptop (French)

Tags: keyboard, dell, laptop

On my laptop (Dell XPS13) Ubuntu 22.04 several keys on my French keyboard stopped to work: <kbd>w</kbd> <kbd>x</kbd> <kbd>c</kbd> <kbd>v</kbd> <kbd>,</kbd> <kbd>;</kbd> <kbd>:</kbd> <kbd>return</kbd> <kbd>caps</kbd>

Everything is fine when I use an external keyboard; in addition, in the BIOS as well the keyboard keys works as intended, so this is not a material issue.

I changed keyboards from "Français obsolète variante" to "Français variante" with no effect.

Comment: Could be a hardware failure. Any coke or coffee related accidents? Does it work on Windows?

Comment: as i wrote, the keyboard works well in the BIOS so coffee is not suspected

Comment: If you have Windows installed in a dualboot setup, does the keyboard work there? Does the keyboard work if you boot from the live Ubuntu installation USB?

Comment: Checked: in an USB live session, problem disappears, keys work (I don't have alternative OS)